# How to derive $E(XX^T)$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I've seen the identity of
$$X \sim \mathcal{N}(m, \Sigma) ~ \Rightarrow ~ E[xx^T] = \Sigma+mm^T $$
in the matrix cookbook. How does one derive this term? (Also, how does it look like for any random distribution $X$?)

Comment: What have you actually tried? If you write out the definition of $\Sigma$ component wise, it should come fairly immediately.

Comment: $E[X \, X^T] = \Sigma+m\,m^T$ is true for any random variable  $X$ with finite expectation $m$ and covariance $\Sigma$ but not all random variables have these

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\Sigma&=\Bbb{E}\left[(X-m)(X-m)^{\top}\right]\\&=\Bbb{E}\left[XX^{\top}\right]-2\cdot\Bbb{E}\left[Xm^{\top}\right]+\Bbb{E}\left[mm^{\top}\right]~~~~~~~~~\left(\text{since}~\Bbb{E}\left[Xm^{\top}\right]=\Bbb{E}\left[mX^{\top}\right]\right)\\&=\Bbb{E}\left[XX^{\top}\right]-2\cdot\Bbb{E}\left[X\right]m^{\top}+mm^{\top}\\&=\Bbb{E}\left[XX^{\top}\right]-mm^{\top}\end{align}$$